# ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT when using npx to create react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
PS C:\Users\User> npx create-react-app client

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\User\client.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-18T02_58_18_148Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting client/ from C:\Users\User
Done.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-react-app "client"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-18T02_58_06_939Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\User>
```

Comment: Sounds like a network problem.

Comment: Try visiting https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint in your browser.

Comment: check your internet connection and try installing again

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with `npx create-react-app app-name` and `create-react-app app-name` with the create-react-app installed globally.

**npm** has little tolerance for slow internet connection unlike *yarn*. I even tried to reset the *timeout* property in the config using the command from the terminal:

```
npm config set timeout 240000
```

Also, tried

```
npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 120000
```

and

```
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 240000
```

None of these worked for me.

Finally, I got rid of the issue by simply using

```
yarn create react-app app-name
```

**yarn** hardly fails on slow connection as it would always try to reconnect and continue its progress from where it stopped.

Install the latest version of *yarn* globally with *npm* using:

```
npm i -g yarn@latest
```

Check if *yarn* was installed with

```
yarn -v
```

Then run `yarn create react-app your-app-name` while in your desired project directory.

Answer (score -1):

This help me

npm -g list

npm install -g create-react-app